# How to resize figures in Quarto (PDF output)?

Tags: pdf, markdown, quarto

I do not get the syntax for resizing graphics in Quarto, could you please give me a hint. The following has no effect.

```
---
title: "resize image"
format: pdf
---

![World](images/World.pdf){fig-width=5}

![World](images/World.pdf){fig-width=10}

![World](images/World.pdf){fig-width=50%}

![World](images/World.pdf){fig-height=50%}
```

https://quarto.org/docs/reference/formats/pdf.html#figures

https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/figures.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `width` and `height`, as documented [here](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/figures.html#pgftikz-graphics).

```
---
title: "resize image"
format: pdf
---

![Elephant with small width](elephant.png){width=10%}

![Elephant with larger height](elephant.png){height=50%}
```

You can also use `px` and `in` as the unit, or specify it between quotes:

```
![Elephant with height=100px](elephant.png){height=100px}

![Elephant](elephant.png){height=2in}

![Elephant](elephant.png){height="100"}
```

---

**Why are `fig-height` and `fig-width` not working?**

As stated in the [document](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/formats/pdf.html#figures) you cite, `fig-height` and `fig-width` are settings for the *default size for figures generated by R or Matplotlib graphics*.

Since your image is not generated by R or Matplotlib, you should use `pandoc`'s attributes, as documented [here](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-link_attributes).

Comment: But this won't be a figure element. How can one control the figure element height?

Comment: With `fig-height`. For it to be a figure element, it has to be the result of a command in R, not with Markdown, e.g. using `jpg::readJPG` or `png::readPNG`.

Comment: I understand that `fig-height` won't work. I am asking how to control the height of a specific figure.

Comment: Note if you are using a chunk option it is out-width and out-height!